# Alternative to this.Controls[textbox].Text = txt; for windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, textbox, controls

I have an issue with the missing '`using System.Windows.Forms;`' in windows phone 7.

this is the current version working on Visual Studio 2010.

```
     public void ChangeTextElement(String textbox, String txt)
        {
            this.Controls[textbox].Text = txt;
        }

   ChangeTextElement("txtMainTextField", txtMainTextField.Text + Environment.NewLine + " Hello world.");
```

It works on windows form application and it doesn't work on windows phone 7.

Any ideas?

Comment: txtMainTextField.Text="Hello world"; thats only is needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Forms is not supported on Windows Phone, only XAML which resembles Silverlight and WPF. If you declare your control in XAML like this:

You can set the text like this:

```
txtMyTextBlock.Text = "whatever string";
```

If you want to find control by name, you need to use `VisualTreeHelper` for finding the `TextBlock` control by name.